# Unable to authenticate with Facebook Login using FirebaseUI and Firebase example source code

Tags: firebase, facebook, authentication, next.js

I forked a [Firebase Github repo](https://github.com/firebaseextended/expense-tracker) that was used during a [demonstration/tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2RZOiUD5E0&list=WL&index=1&t=443s) on the Firebase Youtube Channel.  I was able to host the website using Firebase: [Expense Tracker App](https://djawn-d8dbf.web.app/) but when I tried to add Facebook to the list of authentication providers I couldn't authenticate properly on my development server or the live website.  The application uses the FirebaseUI library [firebaseui-web](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/) (specifically the application uses [firebaseui-web-react](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react) which is a wrapper to the firebaseui-web library) so I read the Firebase documentation ["Before you begin"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui?authuser=0) and performed the following steps:

1. Add Firebase to your JavaScript project.
2. On the Facebook for Developers site, get the **App ID** and an **App Secret** for your app.
3. Enable Facebook Login: (i) In the Firebase console, open the **Auth** section, (ii) On the **Sign in method** tab, enable the Facebook sign-in method and specify the **App ID** and **App Secret** you got from Facebook and (iii) Then, make sure your **OAuth redirect URI** (e.g. my-app-12345.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler) is listed as one of your **OAuth redirect URIs** in your Facebook app's settings page on the Facebook for Developers site in the Product Settings > Facebook Login config.

My code is exactly what was in the [Github repository](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/expense-tracker/tree/main/mvp) except I added `FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,` after `GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,` which is within the **signInOptions** array on line 27.  When I log in with email/password or Google I'm redirected to the `/dashboard` page and I can view the login details in my Firebase console.  I read that only users who are assigned "roles" to an application in development mode can test the authentication flow so I don't expect anyone reading this explanation will be able to log in properly but as an administrator it doesn't work for me either.  I've found many tutorials where they use another method but I've spent so much time on this stack that I could really use some closure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth";
import {
  EmailAuthProvider,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  FacebookAuthProvider,
} from "firebase/auth";
import {
  Button,
  CircularProgress,
  Container,
  Dialog,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { useAuth } from "../firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase/firebase";
import styles from "../styles/landing.module.scss";

const REDIRECT_PAGE = "/dashboard";

// Configure FirebaseUI.
const uiConfig = {
  signInFlow: "popup", // popup signin flow rather than redirect flow
  signInSuccessUrl: REDIRECT_PAGE,
  signInOptions: [
    EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  ],
};

export default function Home() {
  const { authUser, isLoading } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

  // Redirect if finished loading and there's an existing user (user is logged in)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && authUser) {
      router.push(REDIRECT_PAGE);
    }
  }, [authUser, isLoading]);

  return isLoading || (!isLoading && !!authUser) ? (
    <CircularProgress
      color="inherit"
      sx={{ marginLeft: "50%", marginTop: "25%" }}
    />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Expense Tracker</title>
      </Head>

      <main>
        <Container className={styles.container}>
          <Typography variant="h1">Welcome to Expense Tracker!</Typography>
          <Typography variant="h2">
            Add, view, edit, and delete expenses
          </Typography>
          <div className={styles.buttons}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              onClick={() => setLogin(true)}
            >
              Login / Register
            </Button>
          </div>
          <Dialog onClose={() => setLogin(false)} open={login}>
            <StyledFirebaseAuth
              uiConfig={uiConfig}
              firebaseAuth={auth}
            />
          </Dialog>
        </Container>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are trying to log in to a Facebook profile that is attached to the same email that you've used to log in to Google?

Check out the issues opened [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/921) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4926). I haven't tried yet, but I believe the issue can be overcome by building your own UI.

I also discovered that you can at least clear the bug within a session by deleting the session storage item `firebaseui::pendingEmailCredential`